# I can't load more than one post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Good time,

I am using AJAX for loading more posts in wordpress.
But I can't get more than 3 post with wp_query and loop.

My AJAX code :

```
$('#fetchArticle').click(function (html){
var offset = 0;
let current_page = document.querySelector(".posts_list").dataset.page;
let max_page = document.querySelector(".posts_list").dataset.max;
offset = offset + 3;
$(this).text('wait...');
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
$btnLoad = $(this);
$val = $btnLoad.val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'moreArticle.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data : {'html' : 'html'},
    cache: false,
    success : function (response){
        $('#Articles').append(response);
        $btnLoad.prop('disabled', false);
        $btnLoad.text('load more ? ');
    },
    error: function ($e){
        alert('server connection is feild....!');
        $btnLoad.prop('disabled', false);
        $btnLoad.text('try agian !');
        console.log($e);
    }

})
```

})

and my php code is :

```
<?php
session_start();
require( 'wp-load.php' );
$args = array(
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => '3',
'offset' => '3'
);
$my_post = new WP_Query( $args );
$html = '';
$outPut = array();
while ($my_post->have_posts()) {
    $my_post->the_post();
    $pic = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
    $title = get_the_title();
    $categories = get_the_category();
    $cat = $categories[0]->name;
    function excerpt2($num) {
        $limit = $num+1;
        $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
        array_pop($excerpt);
        $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt). " ...";
        return $excerpt;
    }
    $ex = excerpt2(10);
    $author = get_the_author();
    $time = get_the_time();
    $link = get_the_permalink();
    $html .= '<div class="col-md-4"><div class="card card-blog"><div class="card-image"><a         href="#pablo"><img class="img" alt="'.get_the_title().'" src="'.$pic.'" /></a></div>';
$html .= '<div class="card-content"><h6 class="category text-danger"><i class="material-icons"></i>'.$cat.'</h6><h4 class="card-title"><a href="#pablo">'.$title.'</a></h4>';
$html .= '<div class="footer text-center"><div class="author"><a href="#pablo"><span>'.$author.'</span><img src="" alt="..." class="avatar img-raised"></a></div>';
$html .= '<div class="stats"><i class="material-icons">schedule</i>'.$time.'</div>';
$html .= '<a href="'.$link.'" class="btn btn-primary btn-round"><i class="material-icons">format_align_right</i> ادامه مطلب</a></div></div></div>';
wp_reset_postdata();
array_push($outPut , $html);

}
echo $outPut;
```

But every time I request, the browser gives me this : alert('server connection is field....!');

I'm really confused!
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ajax error handler is triggered when the XHR fails what does browser console show about that network request?

Comment: You can see in this picture : https://ibb.co/RSnH2Nx

Comment: OK you are getting Error 500 from the server. What is in the response body? Have you turned on error displaying messages from PHP, or any other error logging mechanism active?

Comment: Not
How do I do this?

Comment: Showing response body - https://ibb.co/2WCHPvt (preview or response tab, depends on response type which is more useful). Displaying php errors - error_reporting=E_ALL and display_errors=on in php.ini or whatever ini file your php environment setup uses